# Permiso denegado para acceder a la camara, Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

estoy haciendo una app en xamarin, android y al momento de acceder a la camara no me deja porque me genera un error sin embargo los permisos en el `AndroidManifest.xml` estan todos.Y lo estoy ejecutando desde mi celular.

Aqui les dejo el codigo donde llamo para que se inicie la camara:

```
Intent inte = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
StartActivityForResult(inte, 0);
```

Aqui les dejo el error que me genera en el StartActivityForResult:

> Java.Lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
>   act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE
>   cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera } from ProcessRecord{d472642d0
>   20417:com.companyname.DigitalClaimT/u0a317} (pid=20417, uid=10317)
>   with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA --->

espero que puedan ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definir algunos permisos como el de `CAMERA` en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` no es suficiente si usas un dispositivo con sistema operativo Android 6.0 o posterior**, tienes que realizar una petición manual.

[**Permisos en Xamarin.Android**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows)

Define una variable :

```
int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 101;
```

y agrega el código para revisar y requerir el permiso en caso de no tenerlo.

```
if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Permission.Granted) {

        //Si no se tiene el permiso lo requiere al usuario
        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(thisActivity, new String[]{Manifest.Permission.Camera}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);

    }
}
```

Debes agregar el método `OnRequestPermissionsResult()` el cual se encargara de manejar la respuesta.

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, 
          string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA : {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.Length > 0 && grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted) {

                //El permiso se acepto.


            } else {

                //El permiso NO fue aceptado.

            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente aunque tienes el permiso en el manifest, hay ciertos permisos delicados que requieren la aprobación del usuario para poder acceder a ellos. Los cuales son permisos sensibles.
A partir de android 6 se implemento la solicitud a los usuarios para acceder

**EL código para ello es el siguiente:**

Primero la verificación de si se cuenta con el permiso:

```
if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera) == (int)Permission.Granted) 
{
    // We have permission, go ahead and use the camera.
} 
else 
{
    // Camera permission is not granted. If necessary display rationale & request.
}
```

Y una vez se ve que no se tiene el permiso se procede a solicitarlo al usuario:

```
if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera)) 
{
    // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
    // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
    // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
    Log.Info(TAG, "Displaying camera permission rationale to provide additional context.");

    var requiredPermissions = new String[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation };
    Snackbar.Make(layout, 
                   Resource.String.permission_location_rationale,
                   Snackbar.LengthIndefinite)
            .SetAction(Resource.String.ok, 
                       new Action<View>(delegate(View obj) {
                           ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, requiredPermissions, REQUEST_LOCATION);
                       }    
            )
    ).Show();
}
else 
{
    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera }, REQUEST_LOCATION);
}
```

La respuesta de la solicitud caerá en el siguiente método:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION) 
    {
        // Received permission result for camera permission.
        Log.Info(TAG, "Received response for Location permission request.");

        // Check if the only required permission has been granted
        if ((grantResults.Length == 1) && (grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)) {
            // Location permission has been granted, okay to retrieve the location of the device.
            Log.Info(TAG, "Location permission has now been granted.");
            Snackbar.Make(layout, Resource.String.permission_available_camera, Snackbar.LengthShort).Show();            
        } 
        else 
        {
            Log.Info(TAG, "Location permission was NOT granted.");
            Snackbar.Make(layout, Resource.String.permissions_not_granted, Snackbar.LengthShort).Show();
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Aqui una pequeña guia o si deseas aprender mas sobre ello, y de como se implementa en xamarin:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=macos

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue de mucha ayuda, ahora funciona correcto

Comment: Hola Dindaka, en la segunda parte estas revisando por permisos de geolocalización "AccessFineLocation" !

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, corrijo la respuesta. Saludos.